# SQL How to display highest value of counter of x by distinct y

Tags: sql

Let's say I have the following table:

| customer | country | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | UK | London |
| Jeremy | UK | London |
| Steven | UK | Manchester |
| Paul | USA | Detroit |
| Jorge | Brazil | Sao Paolo |
| Antonio | Brazil | Sao Paolo |

I want the table to show me all customers from the city with the most orders in a given country, so for example for the chart above I wouldn't get Steven's value because London has more orders than Manchester within U.K

I would also like the table to show me how many customers are from that given city

and so I would like to get...

| customer | country | city | ctr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | UK | London | 2 |
| Jeremy | UK | London | 2 |
| Paul | USA | Detroit | 1 |
| Jorge | Brazil | Sao Paolo | 2 |
| Antonio | Brazil | Sao Paolo | 2 |

thx for the help

Comment: What happened to Steven from Manchester's record?

Comment: Do you have any 'orders' table?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want it to not show customers from Manchester because there are more customers from another city within U.K being London

Comment: Please always tag your SQL requests with the DBMS you are using. You would probably have gotten a working solution hours ago, had you done so. I've posted a standard SQL answer. It should work in most RDBMS, but it doesn't in all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three steps are needed:

1. count the number of rows per country and city
2. get the maximum count for each country
3. only keep rows the count of which matches their country's maximum count

The query:

```
select
  customer, country, city, cnt
from
(
  select
   customer, country, city, cnt,
   max(cnt) over (partition by country) as max_cnt
  from
  (
    select
      customer, country, city,
      count(*) over (partition by country, city) as cnt
    from mytable
  ) counted
) counted_with_max
where cnt = max_cnt;
```